# How find duplicate values and corresponding them value wchich are not the same

Tags: vba, excel

I have the table in Excel:

```
     A    B        C
    12   Novak    Bern
    73   Bayda    Frankfurt
    1    Schmidt  Koln
    12   Novak    Bern
    9    Beckhan  Paris
    11   Youd     Warsaw
    73   Dosed    Kiev
```

I'd like find and highlight all rows which:
-value in column "A" are the same (duplicate values) like:
Cells(2,1) And Cells(7,1) 
- AND corresponding them value in column "C" are NOT the same

How can I do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell D1:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A$7,A1)>1,IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C$7,C1)>1,"","Bad"),"")
```

Copy it down to D7.

I got the idea from here:[find duplicates in excel](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-to-find-duplicates-in-excel-245163/)

Here is some VBA that worked for me.  I looked at some of your other questions and I think you'll be able to see how it works and modify it in case it is not exactly what you are looking for. Basically it loops through the cells and inside the loop it uses the Find function.

```
Sub MacroFind()
Dim strAddress As String
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim strCell As String
Dim startingCellFoundAlready As Boolean
Dim colCValue As String

With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

    For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    strCell = cell.Address
    colCValue = cell.Offset(0, 2).Value

    startingCellFoundAlready = False

            With Worksheets("SheetSomething").Range("a:a")

                Set c = .Find(cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)

                If Not c Is Nothing Then
                    Do
                        strAddress = c.Address
                        If ((strCell <> strAddress) And (c.Offset(0, 2).Value <> colCValue)) Then
                            c.Offset(0, 5).Value = "Bad"
                            c.Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' Blue highlight
                            c.Offset(0, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 37 ' Blue highlight
                        End If

                        If (startingCellFoundAlready = True) Then
                            Exit Do
                        End If

                        If ((strCell = strAddress) And (startingCellFoundAlready = False)) Then
                            startingCellFoundAlready = True
                        End If

                        Set c = .FindNext(c)

                    Loop While Not c Is Nothing
                End If

            End With

        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: And how to do it in vba?